# Как в wordpress в плагине woocommerce добавить свой способ сортировки товаров?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

В woocommerce доступны функции сортировки по цене и рейтингу. Но как добавить сортировку по тому, есть ли на товар скидка и по произвольному полю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться хуком `woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args`

```
function alphabetical_shop_ordering($sort_args)
{
    $orderby_value = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? woocommerce_clean($_GET['orderby']) : apply_filters('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby'));
    if ('alphabetical' == $orderby_value)
    {
        $sort_args['orderby'] = 'title';
        $sort_args['order'] = 'asc';
        $sort_args['meta_key'] = '';
    }
    return $sort_args;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'alphabetical_shop_ordering');

function custom_wc_catalog_orderby($sortby)
{
    $sortby['alphabetical'] = 'Sort by Name: Alphabetical';
    return $sortby;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_wc_catalog_orderby');
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_wc_catalog_orderby');
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я бы добавил: чтобы сортировать мета поля нужно указывать следующие параметры в sort_args: 

$sort_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';  sort_args['meta_key'] = 'name_of_meta_field';